# How to prevent a user with guest privileges to access pages with Administrator privileges by typing the URL in the browser?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, web.xml, servlet-filters

The code I used to prevent a user from accessing a URL without login
is as follows:

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Filtro_Autenticar</filter-name>
    <filter-class>Controlador.Filtro_Autenticar</filter-class>   
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filtro_Autenticar</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/vistas/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Filtro_Autenticar.java

```
public class Filtro_Autenticar implements Filter {
    public void doFilter (ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session;
        if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest){
            session = ((HttpServletRequest)req).getSession();
            //Eliminar la caché
            HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            hsr.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
            hsr.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            hsr.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
            //Verificar si la sesion es diferente de null
            if (session.getAttribute("user") != null) {
                //solo deja pasar a la zona restringida al usuario
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            } else {             
                ((HttpServletResponse)res).sendRedirect(((HttpServletRequest)req).getContextPath()+ "/index.jsp");
            }
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        String exclude= filterConfig.getInitParameter("exclude"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
 }
```

Doing use of this code could restrict access to some jsp pages
 depending on the user who has logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You need in some way to store a usertype in the session. How you would get the usertype into the session depends on your implementation.  For example, when the user logs in, you could look that up from a database table and put it in the session.

In your login code:

```
 session.setAttribute("usertype", usertype_from_db);
```

At the top of pages you are restricting access to, before you start printing anything:

```
 String usertype = (String)session.getAttribute("usertype");
 if(!"admin".equals(usertype))
 {
   response.sendRedirect("unauthorized.jsp");
   return; //necessary to make the redirect happen right now
 }
```

Comment: I am Sending user data in this way `request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);` and I get the data in this way `Usuario user = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("user");`  and now the condition is as follows:

Comment: `if (session.getAttribute("user") != null) {
            if("0".equals(user.getGrupo().toString())){
             chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }else{
            }
            //solo deja pasar a la zona restringida al usuario
           
        } else {
            //redirecciona al index.jps
            ((HttpServletResponse)res).sendRedirect(((HttpServletRequest)req).getContextPath() + "/index.jsp");
        }` and now how to make when the filter is equal to 1